# Extracting a selected item in a ListBox c#

Tags: c#

I have a list box that displays members of a `List<Student>` where `Student` is a class that has some properties like name etc.. I also have a list box that displays members of a 'List`where`Paper`is similar to`Student`.

How do I get the selected `Student` and `Paper` and add them to a `dict {Paper.Name:Student.Name}` when a button is clicked ?

I have tried
`Form2`

`selectedStudent_Form2 = studentListBox_Form2.SelectedItem;`

But I get an error saying

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'TestProjectForProject5.Student'.`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you added names of the students to the listBox, then you can search through your data structure for the selected name (nameToSearch).

```
string nameToSearch = studentListBox_Form2.SelectedItem.ToString();

foreach (Student s in students) { //or use a for loop
    if (s.Name == nameToSearch) {
        //code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a SelectionChanged event on your first listbox

```
LB1.SelectionChanged += LB1_SelectionChanged;
```

Then implement the SelectionChanged method like so:

```
   oid LB1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    LB2.SelectedItems.Clear();
    foreach(var selected in LB1.SelectedItems)
    {
        LB2.SelectedItems.Add(selected);
    }
}
```

Note: LB = Listbox

Answer (score 0):

ListBox.SelectedItem always returns object type value. So you cant directly assign that selectedItem to student. You need to cast it. But you can't simple cast anything into student type. If you have set student as displayValue then only you can cast selectedItem as student. But I do not think you have set displayValue as student, you may have set displayValue as student's Name.

so what you can do, is to set displayValue of both listBox (student as well as paper) to respectively student's name and Paper's Name. 
now you will get studentName by studentListBox_Form2.SelectedItem.ToString() and
Papername by paperListBox_Form2.SelectedItem.ToString().

Now you can use them as key and value pair to add into dictionary